# How can I better get a collection from a collection within a collection?

Tags: c#

As you can see from the code below am building up a collection of objects from within a list within a list. Wondering if there is a better way of writing this nasty method.

Cheers in Advance

```
private List<ListINeed> GetListINeed(Guid clientId)
         {
         var listINeed = new List<objectType>();
             someobject.All(p =>
                                 {
                                     p.subcollection.All(q =>
                                                        {
                                                            listINeed.Add(q.subObject);
                                                            return true;
                                                        });
                                     return true;
                                 });
             return listINeed;
         }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
private List<ListINeed> GetListINeed(Guid clientId)
{
    return someobject.SelectMany(p=> p.subcollection)
                             .Select(p=>p.subObject).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that much appreciated! Didn't think of using the SelectMany method and thought the All returing a bool a little silly!

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in using query syntax you would right this.

```
var query = from c in someObject
            from o in c.subCollection
            select o;
```

This makes it a little bit nicer to read in some scenarios, for example

```
var query = from c in someObject
            from o in c.subCollection
            where c.SomeValue > 12
            select o;
```

Personal preference really, I just find the query syntax easier to read. :)

Comment: I actually didn't think of that. I tend to use Lamda expressions more than Query syntax. That does read nicely though. Especially with the added where clause in there.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
return someobject.SelectMany(so=>so.subcollection).Select(o=>o.subObject).ToList();
```

which really pretty much negates the need for a function, unless you plan to do something else in there (as hinted at by the clientId parameter).

Comment: A good point yeah, might even do that. Although if the way I get the objects changes then if it is in a method will not need to refactor elsewhere. Single point of change etc.

Comment: I would return IEnumerable<> rather than a concrete list so you can leave it to the consumer of the method to decide if they want to add additional conditions they can do. Allows deferred execution.

Comment: @BreakingBadCode, if you have to do the operation from more than one place, I completely agree.